# Load average increased after clear the W3cache plugin cache

Tags: php, wordpress, w3c

I have maintained the wordpress blog site. Once i have test my site load average time in JMeter. Before delete the w3cache plugin cache i have initiate load count 100 and  my load average was 05.34MS.

Then I clear the W3Cache plugin all cache and then process the load test in Jmeter. This time i have initiate load count 10 and my load average was passed above 100.84MS.

Please let me know what is the reason load average increased high speed. (I know after clear cache the page load time increase) but above 100MS is too much.

Answer (score 0):

Because W3totcache must repeat to make cache again and make time so long, so, you must delete cache periodically on 1 week or 1 month

If this helpfull, please arrow up